# disable "Add to Cart" when special price date ended

Tags: special-price

I am beginner to magento and want to disable "Add to cart" button when special price to date is ended, is there a way to do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can do,but *need  write some code at yours template file(phtml files)*.

For your requirement,you need to *`check current date is between the special price end date & start date`*.

I assume that **$_product** is *`a product object(Object of Mage_Catalog_Product)`* of a product. ***Check the current date with special price to date(special_date)***.

Then using  js  script `buttonObject.disabled = true;`  disabling  [the  button](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp)

> ```
> $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
> $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
> $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
> $dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
> // check current product special price end end greater then today
> if ($_product->getPrice() > $_product->getFinalPrice() && $dateToday<=$specialPriceToDate $dateToday => $specialPriceFromDate):
> // run js code
> endif;
> ```

Comment: Thank you Amit for your help, but there is many phtml file in my template directory. I add this code to 'template\catalog\product\list.phtml' inside php markup and nothing happened. when use the code above my php editor hint the line begins by 'if' and between $specialPriceToDate and  $dateToday may be has '&&'?